# PHP if [result of function] == "specific string" then echo HTML

Tags: php, wordpress

I gave these projects some titles, and this works nicely:

```
<img alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" src="photoproject1.png"/>
```

which gives me

```
<img alt="project 1" src="photoproject1.png"/>
```

Next I want only certain HTML to render if the project title is "project 1", so I was thinking something like this:

```
<?php if (the_title_attribute() == "project 1") {
    echo '<img src="icoproject1.png" />'
    }
?>
```

Comment: so what's not working, beside the missing semi-colon? you can also use a ternary operator for that.

Answer (score 4):

`the_title_attribute()` automatically echoes the string returned.

You can change that by using `the_title_attribute(array("echo" => false))`.

For more information read the [Wordpress Documentation for `the_title_attribute`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title_attribute).